# How does drf serialize manytomany fields

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

How does DRF by default handle serializing a manytomany?
I see it defaults to render the field as an array of ids ex: [1,2,3]

And only uses 2 queries when I prefetch the related model.
However, when I generate it myself with .values_list('id', flat=True) it makes an extra query for every row.

Models

```
class Fails(models.Model):
    runs = models.ManyToManyField(Runs, related_name='fails')

class Runs(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
```

View

```
class FailsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...
    def get_queryset(self):
    ...
    return Fails.objects.filter(**params).prefetch_related('runs')
```

Serializer

```
class FailsSerializer(QueryFieldsMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    runs = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_failbin_regressions(self, obj):
        runids = self.context.get('runids')
        return obj.runs.values_list('id', flat=True) #this creates an extra query for every row
```

The end goal is to get runs to display a filtered list of runids.

```
return obj.runs.values_list('id', flat=True).filter(id__in=runids)
```

or

```
runs = obj.runs.values_list('id', flat=True)
return [x for x in runs if x in runids] #to avoid an extra query from the .filter
```

I know the filter creates more queries, I assume the prefetch model is lost in the serializerMethodField.

Is there a way of getting the list of ids like drf does it without the extra query cost when I do it manually?
I can't find any documentation on how they implement the manytomany render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By calling:

```
obj.runs.values_list('id', flat=True)
```

you are performing a new DB query. Since it will be called for every instance, you'll have a lot of extra queries.

`prefetch_related` loads the associated instances. So you can interact with the Python objects without extra queries. You could fix your issue with:

```
def get_failbin_regressions(self, obj):
    runids = self.context.get('runids')
    return [run.id for run in obj.runs.all() if run.id in runids]
```